# Need monthly report where I need summation of Qty for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table STOCK_REGISTER where I have columns Id, ItmId, Qty, CreatedDate. And there are daily transaction data like item inward, outward and all.

Now I am developing one Monthly Report where I want to display Day wise summation of item qty for whole month. I have written following query to do so.

```
SELECT CONVERT(Date,CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate,ItmId, SUM(Qty)
FROM   STOCK_REGISTER
GROUP BY CONVERT(Date,CreatedDate),ItmId
```

This query returns correct data but if I am asking for April-2017 data and STOCK_REGISTER don't have any record on 5th April then it's not displaying 5th April at all where I need 0 value in qty for that item in 5th April.

Can you help me out to get this type of data?

Edit :

I have created query which gives all days of any particular month and have applied left join with STOCK_REGISTER, but still not solving my issue.

```
declare @month int, @year int

set @month = 4

set @year = 2017

SELECT  CAST(CAST(@year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME) + A.Number AS STKFG_CREATED_DATE,
        B.STKFG_ITM_ID,
        0 AS OPENING_STOCK,
        SUM(STKFG_QTY)
FROM    master..spt_values A
        LEFT JOIN STOCK_REGISTER_FG B
ON          CONVERT(DATE,CAST(CAST(@year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME) + A.Number) = CONVERT(DATE,B.STKFG_CREATED_DATE)
        AND C.ITM_ID = B.STKFG_ITM_ID
WHERE type = 'P'
    AND (CAST(CAST(@year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME) + A.Number ) <
        DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(CAST(@year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME) )
    AND STKFG_TRAT_ID = 6
GROUP BY A.Number, B.STKFG_ITM_ID
ORDER BY B.STKFG_ITM_ID,CAST(CAST(@year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME) + A.Number
```

Comment: You could have a generic calendar table and use that table as the source for the dates via left join.

Comment: If certain dates simply aren't present in your data set, then you need to bring them in somehow.  A calendar table is one option.

Comment: what is the dates range you need this data?

Comment: 2 ways:1-Whatever thing is inserting data in your `STOCK_REGISTER ` table,plan such a way that if no exports imports occurs then also it inserts data at the end of the day with the current date.2-create a table with whole year dates `(SELECT to_date('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + rownum - 1 AS all_date FROM   dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365;)` and do left join with your table.

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno I have already use that logic. I have get all days from a query and have applied left join with my table but still I am not getting records where dates are not present

Comment: @ShakeerMirza I don't need date range, I need monthly data.

Comment: @prabhatmishra 1st way is not possible, I have 400+ items and it's not worth to enter 400 entries.

Comment: for each item id you need such kind of report?

Comment: @prabhatmishra I want single report for all 400 items for all 30 days. Then I will create CrystalReport and will Apply GroupSection with ItmId which will display all dates in item group.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your comments.

I have found one solution which works fine for me.

Here #TEMP_TABLE contains all dates.

```
SELECT  A.CREATED_DATE,B.ITM_NAME,ISNULL(C.STKFG_QTY,0)
FROM    #TEMP_TABLE A
        CROSS APPLY ITEM_MASTER B
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,STKFG_CREATED_DATE) AS STKFG_CREATED_DATE, STKFG_ITM_ID, SUM(STKFG_QTY) AS STKFG_QTY
                    FROM    STOCK_REGISTER_FG GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,STKFG_CREATED_DATE),STKFG_ITM_ID) C
ON          CONVERT(DATE,A.CREATED_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE,C.STKFG_CREATED_DATE)
            AND B.ITM_ID = C.STKFG_ITM_ID
ORDER BY B.ITM_NAME,A.CREATED_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below script. Here @tblData  is your actual table name.

```
     declare @tblData table

(id int,datecolumn date)
INSERT INTO @tblData
        (id,datecolumn)

 SELECT 1,'2010-01-01' UNION ALL  
 SELECT 3,'2010-01-01' UNION ALL  
 SELECT 1,'2010-01-03' UNION ALL  
 SELECT 2,'2010-01-04' UNION ALL      
 SELECT 1,'2010-01-05' UNION ALL  
 SELECT 3,'2010-01-06' UNION ALL  
 SELECT 1,'2010-01-10' UNION ALL  
 SELECT 1,'2010-01-10' UNION ALL  
 SELECT 2,'2010-01-11' UNION ALL  
 SELECT 1,'2010-01-11' UNION ALL  
 SELECT 2,'2010-01-11' UNION ALL   
 SELECT 1,'2010-01-12'  UNION ALL          
 SELECT 3,'2010-01-13' 



DECLARE  @MaxDate DATE, 
         @MinDate DATE, 
         @iDate  DATE 

DECLARE  @DateSequence TABLE( 
                          DATE1 DATE 
                          ) 

SELECT @MaxDate = Convert(DATE,Max(datecolumn)), 
       @MinDate = Convert(DATE,Min(datecolumn)) 
FROM   @tblData -- Put your month condition 

SET @iDate = @MinDate 

WHILE (@iDate <= @MaxDate) 
  BEGIN 
    INSERT @DateSequence
    SELECT @iDate 

    SET @iDate = Convert(DATE,Dateadd(DAY,1,@iDate)) 
  END 

SELECT  a.DATE1 ,isnull(sum(b.id),0) as total
FROM   @DateSequence a left join @tblData b on a.DATE1=b.datecolumn
group by a.DATE1
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hello, This solution will not work in my case as I have one more field in @tblData, which is ItmId and i also want group by ItmId. Actually I have 400 items in Item_Master and what I want is all 400 items with all 30 days of month means it should be 12000 records whether qty is zero or anything else.

Comment: Then add item id in select as well as in group by

Comment: I have already tried, by doing so it will not give details of all dates.

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(DATE,A.CREATED_DATE),SUM(STKFG_QTY),B.STKFG_ITM_ID
 FROM #TEMP_TABLE A
   LEFT JOIN STOCK_REGISTER_FG B
 ON   CONVERT(DATE,A.CREATED_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE,B.STKFG_CREATED_DATE)
 GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,A.CREATED_DATE),B.STKFG_ITM_ID             Here I have 1-Apr-2017 to 30-Apr-2017 in #TEMP_TABLE

Comment: As per your script i guess it will return not your expected result But for example let say for date 2010-01-01 item no. 100 is sold twice with quantity 1 and 3 then it should return result as below                                                        2010-01-01 ( date)  100 (item no) 4 (as total quantity)    right ?                       and for date 2010-01-02 there is no item is sold then out put be like            2010-01-02 (date)  0 (item no) 0 (as total quantity). Is this your requirement or some thing different then please share some output format

Comment: Yes. But it's not displaying 0 in 2010-01-02.

Comment: It is displaying null right, the thing is you have not added isnull function for item id like  added for quantity.Also do some deep dive in your code  why results are not coming